# Redirect index.php and any query string to root folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this simple htacess to redirect index.php to root folder:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

I found that it still keeps the query strings attached to the index.php. For example:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?query=string
```

Will be redirected:

```
http://domain.com/?query=string
```

How to get rid of any query string as well?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond: _“When you want to erase an existing query string, end the substitution string with just a question mark.”_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [`QSD`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd) flag when redirecting:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [QSD,R=301,L]
```

Though, as mentioned in the Apache docs

> This flag is available in version 2.4.0 and later.

---

For older Apache versions, you can discard them by passing your own query string:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

Notice the lonely `?` in redirect.

Comment: i tried it but it did nothing. So that means I have an older Apache version?